# Invoke operation in wcf ria services not able to include foriegn key tables

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, ria

[image: Entity diagram]

Hi.
   I m using a Invoke Operation which return a class "Product"

```
public Product GetProductById(int Id)
        {
            Product Record = this.ObjectContext.Product.Include("Order_Detail").Where(d=>d.ProductID=Id).FirstOrDefault()
            return Record;
        }
```

But i m not able to get Order_Detail in the the completed event of the class

```
InvokeOperation<Product> Invk = ObjProduct.GetProductById();
                Invk.Completed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (!Invk.HasError)
                    {
                        Product ObjProduct = Invk.Value;
                        Order objorder=ObjProduct.Order_Detail;
                    }
                };
```

i m getting ObjProduct.Order_Detail as Null i not known why i m not able to include Order_Detail in this Product entity

I have written [Include] in metadata as well

```
[Include]
public Order Order { get; set; }
```

But Still i m not able to get Order_Detail In the collection.
Waiting for a positive response.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you want to get an order out of your product ? Basing on your schema I can just see Order -->> Order_Detail --> Order. Can you explains it ?

Comment: Sorry  i want Order_Detail from Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Invokes are meant to execute an operation on the server or retrieve a simple object. 
 As you can see, the InvokeOperation callback don't contains the usual Entities/AllEntities properties that make room for Included Entities. 
 I suggest you to use a standard load operation with a parameter to get your data.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProductById(int Id)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Product.Include("Order_Detail").Where(d=>d.ProductID=Id);
    }
```

If what you're trying to achieve is "Non Accumulating Execution" (i.e. don't load your domainContext's entityContainer with the result of the query) than have a look at this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/digital_ruminations/archive/2010/04/21/direct-entityquery-execution-non-accumulating-execution.aspx) from Mathew Charles